# Which ProductDetail to use to Launch Purchase Flow in PlayBilling v5

Tags: android, google-play-console, play-billing-library

I have four subscription products

1. Monthly subscription (Auto Renew) with Trial Offer
2. Monthly subscription (Prepaid)
3. Yearly subscription (Auto Renew) with Trial Offer
4. Yearly subscription (Prepaid)

After Connection to Google play is established. I query for products available to buy

```
val subscriptionProductList = listOf(
            QueryProductDetailsParams.Product.newBuilder()
                .setProductType(BillingClient.ProductType.SUBS)
                .setProductId("premium_sub")
                .build()
        )

val params = QueryProductDetailsParams.newBuilder()
            .setProductList(subscriptionProductList)
            .build()

billingClient.queryProductDetailsAsync(params) {
                billingResult, productDetailsList ->
            val productDetail = productDetailsList[0] // only one subscription product
            val subscriptionOfferDetails = productDetail!!.subscriptionOfferDetails

            for (subscriptionOfferDetail in subscriptionOfferDetails!!){
                Log.d("subscriptionOffer", "------")
                Log.d("subscriptionOffer", subscriptionOfferDetail.offerTags.toString())
                Log.d("subscriptionOffer", subscriptionOfferDetail.offerId.toString())
                Log.d("subscriptionOffer", "------")
 
            }
        }
```

The method returns, six,  6 `ProductDetails.SubscriptionOfferDetails` the additional two came from the trial offers, that is one each from auto renew monthly and yearly plan.

If I am going to offer the auto renew monthly subscription which `ProductDetails.SubscriptionOfferDetails` should I use?

For locales (eg India) that require subscriptions to be prepaid does Google play returns products only valid for specific users?